# Selenium finds A tag but click() has no effect?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webobjects

I have a dynamic web application built with WebObjects. There is a link that my test code is trying to find. I do a getPageSource() right before I find it and that is below.

I find the  tag successfully. Then I click on it. Nothing happens. The tag I am looking for on the next page does not get found.

So, what about a  tag can make it not respond to the click? There is no js attached to it. It is inside a span and surrounds an image, but that is all.

When the test code finishes executing, I can click on the link manually and I see the next page. So what up? Any ideas?

```
 [java] [1374173126242]: Going to Schedule page
 [java] [1374173126260]: 
 [java] <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 [java] <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
 [java]     <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
 [java]     <meta content="COM" name="keywords" />
 [java]     <title>APP!</title>
 [java]     <link href="/cgi-bin/WebObjects/APP.woa/_wr_/wodata=/Users/ME/Projects/APP/WebServerResources/APP/login.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 [java] 
 [java]     <link href="/cgi-bin/WebObjects/APP.woa/_wr_/wodata=/Users/ME/Projects/APP/WebServerResources/APP/APP.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 [java] 
 [java]   </head>
 [java]   <body>
 [java]     
 [java]     ( some bits removed . . . )
 [java]     <div id="landing_page_main" class="welcomeBox">
 [java]       <div class="main_cont">
 [java]         <div class="logo"><img src="/cgi-bin/WebObjects/APP.woa/_wr_/wodata=/Users/ME/Projects/APP/WebServerResources/APP/APP-live.png" alt="APP LIVE" /></div>
 [java]         <div class="table">
 [java]           <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 [java]             <tbody><tr>
 [java]               <td valign="middle" align="center">
 [java]                 <span title="Access My Schedule"><a name="19" class="access_my_schedule_link" href="/cgi-bin/WebObjects/APP.woa/wo/Tbrd5n8SsAGIL22d7hkPCM/2.19"><img width="74" border="0" height="64" src="/cgi-bin/WebObjects/APP.woa/_wr_/wodata=/Users/ME/Projects/APP/WebServerResources/APP/arrowRight.png" ismap="ismap" /></a></span>
 [java]               </td>
 [java]             </tr>
 [java]           </tbody></table>
 [java]         </div>
 [java]       </div>
 [java]     </div>
 [java]   
 [java] </body></html>
 [java] [1374173126320]: found element:
 [java]     [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (7ac7e5e2-d4e2-334b-9d99-2e6ddb7b7439)] -> class name: access_my_schedule_link]
 [java] [1374173126332]: element enabled? true
 [java] [1374173126342]: element selected? false
 [java] [1374173126362]: element displayed? true
 [java] [1374173126389]: element location: (620, 265)
 [java] [1374173126404]: element tagName: a
 [java] [1374173126431]: element text: 
 [java] Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for APPLiveDriver$4@337b4703
 [java] Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:33:32'
 [java] System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.6.8', java.version: '1.6.0_51'
 [java] Driver info: driver.version: APPLiveDriver
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:259)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
 [java]     at APPLiveDriver.scheduleAndBack(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at APPLiveDriver.main(Unknown Source)
 [java] Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"breadcrumb_home_link"}
 [java] Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
 [java] For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
 [java] Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:33:32'
 [java] System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.6.8', java.version: '1.6.0_51'
 [java] Session ID: 7ac7e5e2-d4e2-334b-9d99-2e6ddb7b7439
 [java] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
 [java] Capabilities [{platform=MAC, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=21.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
 [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor14.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByClassName(RemoteWebDriver.java:388)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByClassName.findElement(By.java:371)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
 [java]     at APPLiveDriver$4.apply(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at APPLiveDriver$4.apply(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
 [java]     ... 2 more
 [java] Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"breadcrumb_home_link"}
 [java] Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:33:32'
 [java] System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.6.8', java.version: '1.6.0_51'
 [java] Driver info: driver.version: unknown
 [java]     at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///var/folders/oZ/oZFKAiJ8FC80oMT1b--WME+++TQ/-Tmp-/anonymous4201752404452189319webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8444)
 [java]     at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///var/folders/oZ/oZFKAiJ8FC80oMT1b--WME+++TQ/-Tmp-/anonymous4201752404452189319webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8453)
 [java]     at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///var/folders/oZ/oZFKAiJ8FC80oMT1b--WME+++TQ/-Tmp-/anonymous4201752404452189319webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10456)
 [java]     at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///var/folders/oZ/oZFKAiJ8FC80oMT1b--WME+++TQ/-Tmp-/anonymous4201752404452189319webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10461)
 [java]     at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///var/folders/oZ/oZFKAiJ8FC80oMT1b--WME+++TQ/-Tmp-/anonymous4201752404452189319webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10401)
```

Comment: Perhaps a hint. If I wait a second and call click() on the same WebElement instance, I get a org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException. But I can successfully re-find the element (it does not exist on the target page) and click() and still there is no effect. Hm....

Answer (score 0):

It seems Selenium webDriver couldn't find element, try to search by xpath. Also it would be nice if you provide html source (it can be copied from firebug).
Upd.: thanks to response. You have class name "breadcrump_home_link" in the code, but different class name in the test: "access_my_schedule_link".

Comment: the getPageSource() got the page source. So this is the page source of the page as last loaded. It is above.

Comment: See the bit that includes: <span title="Access My Schedule"><a name="19" class="access_my_schedule_link" href="/cgi-bin/WebObjects/APP.woa/wo/Tbrd5n8SsAGIL22d7hkPCM/2.19"><img width="74" border="0" height="64" src="/cgi-bin/WebObjects/APP.woa/_wr_/wodata=/Users/ME/Projects/APP/WebServerResources/APP/arrowRight.png" ismap="ismap" /></a></span>

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am on a page that has the link with the class "access_my_schedule_link". I find that link and call click(). If I get to the next page, I will be able to find the thing with class "breadcrumb_home_link". Since the click() is not working, the "breadcrumb_home_link" is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is an answer. I think this might be worth filing as a bug with the selenium people.

I took apart the HTML that WebObjects was creating for me. I was using a WOActiveImage. If I use a WOHyperlink around a WOImage, I got almost the exact same URL, and selenium was able to follow the link.

The difference was this:

```
<a name="19" class="access_my_schedule_link" 
   href="/cgi-bin/...">
<img width="74" border="0" height="64" src="/cgi-bin/..." ismap="ismap" />
</a>
```

became:

```
<a name="19" class="access_my_schedule_link" 
   href="/cgi-bin/...">
<img width="74" border="0" height="64" src="/cgi-bin/..." />
</a>
```

Apparently using the ismap attribute on the A tag is toxic to Selenium. Very odd.

Well, I am good for now.

Answer (score 0):

When you get an exception from the .findElement  method, all you have to do is handle the exception gracefully and if you do it all in a loop, you can retry as many times as you want without crashing your test.   If you look at the .ignoring  method of the FluentWait class, that is an example.

Comment: Removing the ismap="ismap" parameter from the img tag inside the a tag causes selenium to follow the link correctly. Why would that be? How would catching the exception and trying again help?